# Transitive action of SL(2,R) on the circle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

Is the circle a homogeneous space for G=SL(2,R)? I think G/B is real analytically isomorphic to the circle where B is Borel  subgroup of G. Is there a transitive algebraic action of G on the circle? Can someone give that action with formulas for every entry given as rational functions in the entries of g and the circle (take circle as unit circle in the plane).

I tried projecting onto the K circle in the KAN=KB decomposition and then multiplying by that rotation but it didn’t work.

Maybe something with Möbius transformation acting on the circle bounding the upper half plane viewed as a subset of the Reimannian sphere?

Note: the action cannot be an action by isometries the circle is not a symmetric space for SL(2,R) basically because SO(2,R) is not a group quotient of SL(2,R)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, actually in (essentially) two distinct ways.

$G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ acts transitively on the circle $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbf{R}$; the stabilizer of $\infty$ is $B$ (group of upper triangular matrices), so $G/B$ is homeomorphic to the circle. In this case, the action of $G$ on $B$ is not faithful: the kernel is $\{\pm \mathrm{id}\}$.

Also, $G$ acts on the circle $(\mathbf{R}^2\smallsetminus\{0\})/\mathbf{R}_{>0}$, and the stabilizer of $(1,0)$ for this action is $B^+$, the subgroup of index 2 of $B$ with positive diagonal. In this case, the action of $G$ on $G/B^+$ is faithful.

Note that there's a continuous $G$-equivariant surjection $G/B^+\to G/B$, which is a connected 2-fold covering.

Comment: In my question I asked "give that action with formulas for every entry given as rational functions in the entries of g and the circle." Could a give such an algebraic formula for one or both of the actions you named? Or is an action with polynomial/rational formulas somehow impossible because that would imply an action on the circle as the unit circle and $ SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $ cannot act by isometries because there is no surjective homomorphism  $ SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \to SO_2(\mathbb{R}) $?

Comment: It depends on what kind of coordinates you're using for the circle. For the faithful action on the unit circle with Cartesian coordinates, the action should be $$\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}(x,y)=\frac1{\sqrt{(ax+by)^2+(cx+dy)^2}}(ax+by,cx+dy).$$

Comment: Thanks that’s perfect!

Comment: this answer is very nice in that it gives a general action polynomial/ rational function action of $ SL(n,\mathbb{R}) $ on the unit sphere in n space by using the natural left multiplication action and then dividing by the norm of the vector to get back to the unit sphere. However I noticed (as, in fact, you note in your answer above) that this action has stabilizer B+ rather than B. Is there an obvious associated action (explicit and algebraic) with stabilizer B? Perhaps by composing with algebraic double cover$ (x,y) \to  (x^2-y^2,2xy) $ map in an appropriate way?