# Circle as coset space for different groups?

Tags: lie-groups, circles, physics, homogeneous-spaces

The circle $S^1$ can be thought of as the coset space of:

1. Special orthogonal groups, $S^1 \simeq SO(2)/SO(1)$,
2. Orthogonal groups, $S^1 \simeq O(2)/O(1)$.

Which other groups is the circle a coset space for?

Thinking about $S^1$ as a classic configuration space (from a physicist's perspective), which salient features might incline us to represent our circle using one group over another? Of course each is valid mathematically, but it seems there should be some reason we might pick say (1) over (2).

Wikipedia's entry for homogeneous spaces seems to suggest (1) yields the *oriented* sphere whereas (2) does not. What does that mean precisely?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555537/transitive-action-of-sl2-r-on-the-circle in general $ G $ acts transitively on $ S^1 $ is roughly equivalent to $ G $ having a codimension 1 subgroup that contains its Borel subgroup. So (if the action is effective up to discrete kernel) either $ G $ is one dimensional or $ G $ is noncompact.

Comment: I don't know any groups acting effectively besides $ SO_2, O_2, SL_2, PSL_2 $