# G acts effectively implies $ dim(G) \leq \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Suppose that a Lie group $ G $ acts effectively on a manifold $ M $ with $ dim(M)=n $ then is it true that
$$
dim(G) \leq \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
For the special case that $ G $ is compact this can be proven by induction on $ n $ because then we can equip $ M $ with a left $ G $ invariant metric so $ G $ acts by isometries and thus for each $ x $ the orbit $ \mathcal{O}_x \leq M $ has dimension at most $ n $ while the stabilizer $ G_x $ acts effectively on the unit sphere in the tangent space $ T_xM $ and $ G_x $ has dimension at most $ \frac{n(n-1)}{2} $. So
$$
dim(G) = dim(\mathcal{O}_x) + dim(G_x) \leq n+ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $M=\mathbb{R}$. Then there is an effective action by the $2$-dimensional group of affine maps $\{x\mapsto ax+b|a\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\},\,\,b\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Also another example, where $M$ is compact: $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is $3$-dimensional and acts effectively on $S^1=\mathbb{R}P^1$ by Mobius transforms.

Comment: Wow what a fast and thorough yet concise reply.  I love that you included another example with $ M $ compact, that would have been my next question. For more information about $ SL_2 $  acting on the circle see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555537/transitive-action-of-sl2-r-on-the-circle Just a lovely answer, thanks tkf!